# Uppercase a javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Im getting some variable for the URL, but I'm getting as a lowercase and I would like to get it uppercase. This is the javascript that I'm running. How can I get it in Uppercase as return???

thanks

```
    function() {
  var pageUrl = window.location.href;
  return pageUrl.split("/")[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

```js
function foo() {
  var pageUrl = window.location.href;
  return pageUrl.split("/")[3].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(foo());
```

Comment: Works perfectly. thanks!!